# mediasoup is undefined node.js

Tags: node.js, installation, undefined, mediasoup

I am using mediasoup library to create video calls with many people in one room. Having imported npm package, it gives me a message that it is undefined:

```
async createWorker() {
this.worker = await mediasoup.createWorker({
  rtcMinPort: 2000,
  rtcMaxPort: 2080,
});
logger.debug(`worker pid ${this.worker.pid}`);

this.worker.on("died", (error: any) => {
  // This implies something serious happened, so kill the application
  logger.error({
    error: error.toString()
  }, "mediasoup worker has died");
  setTimeout(() => process.exit(1), 2000); // exit in 2 seconds
});
```

}

the error:

```
    C:\Users\andri\Desktop\resume_projects\college_chat\back\src\messaging\socketManager\index.ts:22
    this.worker = await mediasoup.createWorker({
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createWorker')
    at SocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andri\Desktop\resume_projects\college_chat\back\src\messaging\socketManager\index.ts:22:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\andri\Desktop\resume_projects\college_chat\back\src\messaging\socketManager\index.ts:31:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\andri\Desktop\resume_projects\college_chat\back\src\messaging\socketManager\index.ts:27:12)
    at SocketManager.createWorker (C:\Users\andri\Desktop\resume_projects\college_chat\back\src\messaging\socketManager\index.ts:47:16)
    at SocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andri\Desktop\resume_projects\college_chat\back\src\messaging\socketManager\index.ts:123:16)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\andri\Desktop\resume_projects\college_chat\back\src\messaging\socketManager\index.ts:31:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

My node version: v18.17.0
My python version: 3.10.7
I have MSBuild tools installed since I have visual studio on my laptop (I am on Windows).
I have also tried to install this package as administator from a separate terminal - didn't work as well.

Comment: Did you use `require` to load that module?  I don't see it.

Comment: I am using import to load this module (like everywhere in my project):
import mediasoup from 'mediasoup';

Comment: _I am using mediasoup library_: citation needed.  (i.e. show your code by editing your question to include the relevant import code, don't bury important details about your question in comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mediasoup here is imported by its default value, when it does not export a default value (undefined). createWorker is defined as a named export. You can either import all named exports as a variable `import * as mediasoup` or import just createWorker `import {createWorker}`.

The package was installed successfully because if you was importing an invalid package, it would've thrown a "Cannot find module" error.